# Printer drivers on KONICA MINOLTA PP 1350e

Tags: drivers, printing

I had an older printer but can't find drivers. On oficial Konica web they don't have drivers for linux and in google I hadn't found any.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: KONICA MINOLTA drivers for Linux are very rare and they don't work... Problem can be solved by having one Windows printer server on which printers can be installed , and it will work on Linux with NoLinDrivers printer server, you can read full tutorial about how to print from linux WITHOUT needing any linux printer drivers or PPDs here: http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-print-from-linux-without-needing.html

Answer (score 1):

They do offer a download file if you select LINUX in the driver [download site](http://www.konicaminolta.eu/business-solutions/support/download-center/download-result.html?packageId=21644&productName=PagePro%201350E).  But it's just a README file with this:

> Support for KONICA MINOLTA PagePro 1350E/1350EN and Linux /  Mac OS X
>   can be achieved using third party solutions such  as Gimp-Print.
>   ...
>   If "KONICA MINOLTA PagePro 1350E" or "KONICA MINOLTA PagePro  1350EN"
>   printer models are not listed, please use "HP  LaserJet 6 Series"
>   instead.

Note that gimp-print has been replaced by Gutenprint and the drivers are listed under `Minolta` (not Konica)

Answer (score 0):

In the search for new printers menu ( connecting the printer to a port before giving search ) when the computer recognizes Konica minolta page pro ... the select is selected, and the important thing is that when we go printer types to search a compatible driver does not have to look Konica Minolta , MINOLTA but once you select this printer will give pro 6e page and leave us the options to the right:

CUPS + GUTEPRINT v.5.2.3 (also 5.2.3 ) simplied . We continue with the normal installation AND SOLVED !!

Comment: This site is English only please don't post in other languages.  I've translated this for you using google translate.